# call server function from jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

Currently I'm using jQuery on my asp.net content page (using master).  I am creating a modal dialog using jquery.  The div that is defined with the following code

```
<div id="example" class="flora" title="Information" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; text-align:left;">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server">
            Is the information you have entered correct?<br />
            <asp:Label>Some labels filled when the modal appears</asp:Label> 
            <asp:button runat="server" OnClick="someServerSide_Function" Text="Submit" />
        </asp:Panel>
  </div>
```

There is a HTML button that gets pressed, and when the button is pressed, it calls the following code

```
$("#example").dialog("open");
```

And the modal is defined with the following code:

```
$("#example").dialog({
                autoOpen: false, 
                modal: true,
                height: 400,
                overlay: overlayCss,
                bgiframe: true
            });
```

The Modal gets filled when the HTML button is clicked, and the ASP.NET button does not call its server side function when it is clicked.  The Example div resides inside of the  tags, so it should be calling the server side function.  What could be wrong?

Comment: I think we are going to need to see some code to help you.  Can you sanitize the code so that we could get an idea of what you are working on?

Comment: you using asp.net webpages or asp.net mvc?

Comment: First part
$("ctl00_AdditionalScripting_example").addClass("flora").dialog({autoOpen: false,modal: true,height: 400,overlay: overlayCss,bgiframe: true });

(".okButton").click(function(e) {if (validateControls() == true){$("#ctl00_AdditionalScripting_example").dialog("open");e.preventDefault();

Comment: Here is the panel:
<div id="example" title="Information" runat="server"style="display:none; visibility:hidden; text-align:left;"><asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server">Information is here</asp:Panel></div>

I am using an asp.net web application

Comment: You might want to edit your question, and post the code there so that you can format it for readability.  Comments are pretty limited on this site.

Comment: Matter fact it seems like you have errors in the code in the first part from just a quick scan, $("ctl00_AdditionalScripting_example") should be  $("#ctl00_AdditionalScripting_example")

Comment: once you paste in code, you can highlight it and hit the 10101 button to format it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Not nearly enough info to help you probably... but try this link.

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Edit:

It appears this question has been edited so I will edit my answer...

Use the above if you are wanting your button to call the serverside method from jquery without posting the page.

It now appears that you would be correctly calling a server-side method. (the whole page would submit.)

Have you set a break point in your serverside method and make sure that its being called (debugging)?

There really could be a lot wrong without seeing more of your code-behind.

You could also wire up the page with the Onit event with something like

```
this.Button1+=new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

(After giving your button an ID of "Button1")